# How to use function's variables inside function's scope in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Actually I'm new in VHDL, I'm trying to assign a function's variable to a variable declared in functions scope. But I'm getting an error when I'm synthesizing.
I'm using ISE Project Navigator. Here's my code.

```
function moverDerecha(datos : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) RETURN std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) IS
  variable TMP : datos;
    --TMP := datos;
     begin
        TMP(0)<=TMP(2);
        TMP(1)<=TMP(0);
        TMP(2)<=TMP(1);
     return TMP;
end moverDerecha;
```

I hope you could help me! It's part of my homework n.n.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompiler:60 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 32: indexed name is not a type

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompiler:60 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 33: datos is not a type

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompiler:866 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 36: Use := to assign to variable tmp

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompiler:866 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 37: Use := to assign to variable tmp
ERROR:HDLCompiler:866 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 38: Use := to assign to variable tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a *type* for the variable (after the colon):

```
variable TMP : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := datos;
```

You also have to use `:=` and not `<=` to assign to variables:

```
TMP(0) := TMP(2);
TMP(1) := TMP(0);
TMP(2) := TMP(1);
```

---

I do not know if the compiler will optimize this away, but you are essentially setting the variable `TMP` twice. First to copy `datos` then to perform the shift. It's been a while since I've worked with VHDL, but might I suggest:

```
function moverDerecha(datos : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) RETURN std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) IS
    variable TMP : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
    TMP(2 downto 1) := datos(1 downto 0);
    TMP(0) := datos(2);

    return TMP;
end moverDerecha;
```

---

Also it might just be me, but it looks like this function is performing a *left shift*?

Comment: I've tried what you're posting, but the error became different.


ERROR:HDLCompiler:866 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 45: Use := to assign to variable tmp

Comment: @JuanReséndiz I'm guessing line 45 is in a different function?

Comment: Actually one function moves all the content inside the vector to the left and the other one moves it to the right. I decided to just post one of them, both are similar.

Comment: So which line is 45 then?

Comment: From the part of the code that says:
TMP(0)<=TMP(1);

And it the error repeats in both functions, obviously moving each one in different directions.

Comment: Ah yes, you have to use `:=` not `<=` to assign to variables.

Comment: I've corrected that and now there are just 4 errors(2 for each function)

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompiler:60 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 42: indexed name is not a type
ERROR:HDLCompiler:841 - "/home/alberto/Dropbox/Untitled/ESCOM/Sistemas Digitales/Practicas/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/Practica3RegistroEspecifico/RegistroEspecifico.vhd" Line 58: Expecting type std_logic_vector for <moverderecha>.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem. Then, I discovered that the return type should be the generic type i.e if you use an `std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)` for a return type, you should declare it as `return std_logic_vector is`, just omitting the `(1 downto 0)` part.

Comment: This! I wonder why this works this way, why you shouldn't be able to return a concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

I've found why all my functions weren't working.

I decided to use a package and inside of it declare each function. Then adding the

```
library work;
use work.my_package.all;
```

Finally solved all the problems. I know I'm still having a lot of troubles in VHDL, but I'm working on it! :) Thanks to [lc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44853/lc)